# How can I set width&height CircularProgress?

Tags: android, layout

I want to set my CircularProgress' w:300dip h:300dip. But I can't change it. Any idea?

**MyClass.java**

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            300,300);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    lp.setMargins(0,0,0,76);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    TextView textView = new TextView(relativeLayout.getContext());
    textView.setText(modelObject);
    relativeLayout.addView(textView);
    CircularProgressBar c3=new     CircularProgressBar(relativeLayout.getContext());
    relativeLayout.addView(c3);
    c3.setTitle(String.valueOf(yuzdeler[position]));
    c3.setSubTitle("GÜN KALDI");
    c3.setProgress(yuzdeler[position]);
    c3.setLayoutParams(lp);
    collection.addView(relativeLayout);
    return relativeLayout;
```

[image: screen]

Comment: are you using some library???

Comment: yeah, this https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar

Comment: Do you want to set progressbar as same hight and width as relativelayout?

Comment: No, it's too big. I want to set 300x300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set layout param with height and width to `CircularProgressBar`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams circularLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            50,50);
c3.setLayoutParams(circularLp);
```

Comment: wait, it's working. But did you override this again. Cause I defined like this top of the my code.

Comment: No i din't, i just set layout param to your CircularProgressBar

Comment: It's rubbish. I edit my code just like yours but I define one time. It's working NOW. OMG.

Comment: Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 0):

Change it from the xml:

```
<com.lylc.widget.circularprogressbar.example.CircularProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circularprogressbar1"
    style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Holo.CircularProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    circular:subtitle="subtitle"
    circular:title="Title" />
```

Comment: Sorry mate. But I'm using viewpager, so I have to define it programmatically.